# Using a Watson knowledge-studio model directly

Tags: ibm-watson, watson, alchemyapi

Has anyone ever tried to use the model that has been generated by the Watson Knowledge studio outside of the Alchemy language API?

Or do I always need to upload the model to knowledge studio and from then on talk to the api?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though I have always used my Knowledge Studio based models on Natural Language Understanding, I believe it's possible to deploy these models to Discovery and Watson Explorer as well for text extraction.
[Check this documentation](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/knowledge-studio/publish-ml.html#publish-ml) for details on how to deploy the model to different components.

Comment: So I understand it correctly, that you can only use this within one of the IBM/Watson/Bluemix frameworks?

Comment: Yes. We can use it with those Watson services or tools where natural language identification for a specific domain might be necessary. Watson Studio is the tool to train those services.